# how to remove underline for textview in android

Tags: textview, underline

I have seen many questions regarding removing of underline for autolink of textview.

But for me, I am unable to remove underline for normal textview. I set the underline by:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(nameOnTemplateTextview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try

```
 textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));
```

or more broadly just set,

`textview.setPaintFlags(0)`  but the first option is more exact

Comment: In Kotlin: `textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags and Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG.inv()`

Comment: That doesnt work for editTexts

Comment: This does not work

Comment: It is not working on textview.

Answer (score 11):

Here is technique you can try to remove underline from any textview or edit text using the given below example code snippet

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:hint="This is first EditText"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:background="@null"
    />
```

Use of the attribute

`android:background="@null"`

you can remove underline from textview or edit text

You can also try putting transparent color to the background to remove underline beneath a textview.

Comment: There is a background color for textview so i cannot make it null.

Comment: In that case i am not sure about any specific solution but if you do'nt get any solution then in that case keep background: @null but put a framelayout below Textview and give background to that frame layout for this..good luck

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni u mean for input type specified as phone number?

Comment: Nope set auto link for phone number

Comment: Doesn't make any changes on phone type.

Comment: this doesn't work. I tried both android:background="@null" & android:background="@color/white" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late to answer this good question but I share my experience; perhaps it might be helpful for some one.

There is a really practical and easy way to remove underline for a text. And that is:  `textview.setPaintFlags(View.INVISIBLE);`

It works perfect for me.

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120px"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

If you have an underline problem, use this code in textview

android: autoLink = "all"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way, it worked.

Just add `android:background="@null"` this line of code into your EditText xml.

See the example:

```
<EditText
           android:id="@+id/txt_search_field"
           android:lines="1"
           android:background="@null"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```